# internal-error when sending Firebase Email Verification in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a Flutter app where I'm using Firebase for user authentication. I'm trying to register users via email and password, and then sending them an email link for verification. Although user registration works fine, the email for verification isn't sent.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```dart
Future<void> registerWithEmailAndPassword() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _email,
        password: _password,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }

    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
        email: _email,
        actionCodeSettings: _actionCodeSettings,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error sending email verification');
      print(e.code);
      print(e.message);
      print(e.stackTrace);
      return null;
    }
    print('Successfully sent email verification');
  }
```

And my `ActionCodeSettings` is defined as:

```dart
ActionCodeSettings setupActonCodeSettings() {
  return ActionCodeSettings(
    url: 'https://**',
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    iOSBundleId: '**',
    androidPackageName: '**',
    androidInstallApp: true,
    androidMinimumVersion: '16',
  );
}
```

##### Additional Details:

- No emails are received when checking on Gmail.
- I have verified that the email address is correct.
- Firebase libraries are up-to-date.
- Rate limiting is not reached.
- The error displayed is:

  ```
  flutter: Error sending email verification
  flutter: internal-error
  flutter: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.
  flutter: null
  ```

Any insights into what could be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.